# Are files synced from mobile app supposed to download to my PC's Ubuntu One folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

I just installed Ubuntu One files for Android and it uploaded all my pictures and I can see them in the web interface. Can I get this folder to automatically download all the files to my Ubuntu One folder on my Ubuntu PC?

Comment: I have been having the same problem. I am running ubuntu 10.04 so there is no control panel and therefore no option to sync the cloud "synced folder" to my pc

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Your pictures are stored in a cloud folder named "Pictures - *your phone model*". If you run the Ubuntu One control panel (which you can see at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/ControlPanel#Cloud_Folders) then your new cloud folder will be listed, and you can tick it to make sure that this cloud folder is also on your computer.

Comment: OK, I am still on 10.10 so I still have the old Control Panel without that option. I will try to install it, but following the advice here http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2011/06/natty-ubuntuone-control-panel-in.html I get 'Couldn't find package ubuntuone-control-panel' when trying 'sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel' I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: doh, I'm on 10.04 can I still do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should see a new cloud folder called something like "Pictures - Nexus One", which you can specify in the Ubuntu One control panel to sync to your computer.
It doesn't sync down by default, no.